# CodeFirst, model property always null on fetch

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, code-first

I'm using CodeFirst and got stuck at a problem where I'm trying to map 0..1 -- n.
In the model Media I've got a model of type MediaCategory, this one gets a column named MediaCategory_Id and has an Id set in the database. However, when Im fetching the data from the database MediaCategory property is always null. My question is how can i map this so it fetches correct data by the Id it got in the database?

Ive tryed around a lil in the DbContext.cs and haven't got anything to work properly. 
Notice Ive got LazyLoading set to true and Proxy to false in my repository.

**Context**

```
public class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    public BlogContext()
        : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        this.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<BlogContext>());
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().ToTable("Post");
        modelBuilder.Entity<PostMedia>().ToTable("PostMedia");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Media>().ToTable("Media");
        modelBuilder.Entity<MediaCategory>().ToTable("MediaCategory");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Media>().HasRequired(t => t.MediaCategory);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasMany(t => t.MediaList);

    }

}
```

**Models**

MEDIA

```
public class Media
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Title must be given.")]
    [MaxLength(250, ErrorMessage = "Title can't exceeded 250 characters in length.")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "File must be given.")]
    [MaxLength(Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "File exceeded max characters in length.")]
    public string File { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(250, ErrorMessage = "Description can't exceeded 250 characters in length.")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Author must be given.")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Author can't exceeded 50 characters in length.")]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Created date must be given.")]
    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Changed { get; set; }

    public MediaCategory MediaCategory { get; set; }

}
```

MEDIACATEGORY

```
public class MediaCategory
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A title must be given.")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Title can't exceeded 50 characters in length.")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(250, ErrorMessage = "Description can't exceeded 250 characters in length.")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**SOLVED**

```
public virtual MediaCategory MediaCategory { get; set; } and
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true; <-- This one was on false :)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//public MediaCategory MediaCategory { get; set; }
  public virtual MediaCategory MediaCategory { get; set; }
```

Comment: Adding `virtual`. This enables the Lazy Loading feature of Entity Framework. Lazy Loading means that the contents of these properties will be automatically loaded from the database when you try to access them.

Comment: Seems this was needed also. I had it set to false... this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;

Comment: Yes, probably. It's default true for code-first. Also be aware not to simply `new` an object, there should be generated Create() methods.

Answer (score 2):

When you're fetching the data from the database, unless configured, you will have to explicitly define which child objects you want to include.

For example, you may be doing something like:

```
_context.Media.Where( <some expression> );
```

Try changing that to:

```
_context.Media.Where( <some expression> ).Include(m > m.MediaCategory);
```